# react-native-fbsdk close button returning postId = null instead of isCancelled = true

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

There appears to be a bug when clicking the inner close button of the ShareDialog, resolving the promise with `{postId: null}` instead of `{isCancelled: true}`

This only happens when selecting the inner close button. The outer button works fine.

Multiple button example:

[image]

The links are successfully shared though but do not return a postId(always null). Currently I can't determine whether someone closed the dialog or made a successful share...

To make matters stranger, everything works fine - closing the dialog with either button and also returning a valid postId - when using the LoginManager with the "publish_actions" permission and loading the ShareDialog afterwards.

However, Facebook deems the "publish_actions" permission unnecessary when using the ShareDialog.

The problem occurs in my own app and also the sample app found here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/tree/master/sample/HelloFacebook

Other details:

- react-native 0.45.0
- react-native-fbsdk 0.6.0
- android facebook sdk 4.22.1
- problems occurs on emulator and physical device

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this behaviour is part of the android sdk and not a bug. The onSuccess callback is called on closing the share dialog(why I don't know) and also a successful share.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/890116221030179/

So if you need to determine whether a post has been shared it looks like the "publish_actions" permission is needed.